# How to set margin for child DIV element...is there a CSS method to get around this?

Tags: css, html, margin

So working on my site over at [www.buildinghunter.com](http://www.buildinghunter.com).  On our home page we have 4-div elements in the bottom left of the page.

I'm trying to align the two divs (`id=text-9` and `id=text-10`) in the middle with the two on the left (`id=delivered` and `id=savehours`).

When I add those IDs to my CSS page, the margin I add to the IDs gets omitted by DIVs further up.

So my question is this: How can I add margin to those IDs and it get used?  If I modify the CSS on the DIVs further up I risk changing elements across the whole site.

Thanks for any insight and also my apologies if terminology isn't spot on.  Wasn't sure if what I'm having problem with is considered parent/child div issues.

Comment: Can you post HTML and CSS?  A jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) would be great.

Answer (score 0):

from what I can tell, the reason you cannot apply a margin there is because on style.css line 1131 you have declared `margin: 0 !important`. You can override that by declaring changes here as !important as well.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I wound up changing that line to: margin: 10px 0 0 0 and it aligned with no issue.

Answer (score 0):

When I looked at the current markup both id=text-9 and id=text-10 are `<li>` elements nested under `<div id="homemid">` without a surrounding `<ul>` element. When I wrapped both `<li>` elements with the appropriate `<ul>` tag  this corrected the alignment issue (in Chrome and Firefox) without the need to adjust any margin styles.

Comment: Thanks @JamesTracy.  I tried looking for where to add the <ul> but couldn't figure that out.  So instead I changed the margin on the style sheet and it cleared it right up.  Thanks again for the help.